# PowerShell parameters from file

Tags: function, powershell, binding, parameters

I am having some issue in calling a function using named parameters.

This is the declaration of the function in a separate file (Security.ps1):

```
function Add-SSRSItemSecurity
(
    [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$false)]
    [Alias("SSRSrange")]
    [string]$range,[Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$false)]
    [Alias("path")]
    [string]$itemPath,

    [Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$false)]
    [Alias("grp")]
    [string]$groupUserName,

    [Parameter(Position=3,Mandatory=$false)]
    [Alias("SSRSrole")]
    [string]$role,

    [Parameter(Position=2)]
    [bool]$inherit=$true
)
```

I then call this function in another Host.ps1 script as:

```
    Set-Location 'C:\SSRSJobs'
    . .\SSRSsecurity.ps1
```

This call works in the Host file:

```
Add-SSRSItemSecurity -range "server1" -itemPath "/Test" -groupUserName "CN\Group" -role "Browser"
```

I tried to pass in multiple parameters to the function as a loop, but calling new variables each time:

```
$securityArray = @()
$securityArray = Get-Content -Path "C\ReleaseSecurity.txt"
    foreach($line in $securityArray)
    {
        Add-SSRSItemSecurity $line;
    }
```

The file having:

```
-range "server1" -itemPath "/Test" -groupUserName "CN\Group" -role "Browser"
-range "server2" -itemPath "/Test" -groupUserName "CN\Group" -role "Browser"
-range "server3" -itemPath "/Test" -groupUserName "CN\Group" -role "Browser"
```

The error I get is:

```
Add-SSRSItemSecurity : Cannot bind positional parameters because no names were given.
At line:229 char:27
+                         Add-SSRSItemSecurity <<<<  $line;
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-SSRSItemSecurity], ParameterBindingExcepti
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousPositionalParameterNoName,Add-SSRSItemSecurity
```

Inspecting the string, the `$line` variable does hold correct naming for parameters. I've tried all sorts of error trapping, but I'm unable to get a decent error message other than the above. I've also tried forms of quoting, but I cannot get the function to see the name binding.

Can multiple variables be called in a function that are bound to just a PowerShell variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [splatting](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/10/18/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts.aspx) for that. Save the parameters as a CSV like this:

```
"range","itemPath","groupUserName","role"
"server1","/Test","CN\Group","Browser"
"server2","/Test","CN\Group","Browser"
"server3","/Test","CN\Group","Browser"
```

and load it like this:

```psh
Import-Csv 'C:\ReleaseSecurity.txt' | % {
  Add-SSRSItemSecurity @_
}
```

Comment: Ansgar, you genius! I didn't use your code but I did use your method and it works perfectly! Thank you very much :)