# powershell script reading parameters from txt

Tags: powershell, parameters, powershell-4.0

I have a script that takes 2 parameters (name and location).  I put the name and location into a txt file as per this post here [Powershell parameters from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28088460/powershell-parameters-from-file).  I got prompted to put in value for the 2nd parameter:

```psh
Import-Csv 'C:\temp\paramtest.txt' | % { C:\temp\script\paramtest.ps1 @_ }
```

> cmdlet paramtest.ps1 at command pipeline position 1 Supply values for
>   the following parameters: param2:**

This is what my .txt look like:

```psh
"param","param2"
"foo","c:\temp"
"bar","c:\temp"
"foobar","c:\temp"
```

and the Powershell script is just plain:

```psh
Param (
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
    [string]$param, 
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true,Position=2)]
    [string]$param2
    ) 

$greeting='Hello to ' + $param + ' and ' + $param2
Write-Output $greeting
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of PowerShell?

Comment: From Get-Host and $PSVersionTable, I got:Version=4.

Answer (score 4):

When you import the file with `Import-Csv` cmdlet, you get objects of type `PSCustomObject` back.

The [splatting operator (`@`)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955(v=wps.630).aspx) expects a hashtable, not a `PSCustomObject`.

---

## PowerShell 3.0+

To import the parameters from the txt file, you could use [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849900(v=wps.630).aspx) cmdlet to return them as hashtables instead:

```
Get-Content -Path .\test.txt -ReadCount 2 | ForEach-Object {
    $Splat = ConvertFrom-StringData $($_ -join [Environment]::NewLine)
    .\paramtest.ps1 @Splat
}
```

And format your text file like this:

#### text.txt

```
param=foo
param2=c:\\temp
param=bar
param2=c:\\temp
param=foobar
param2=c:\\temp
```

---

## PowerShell 2.0

If you are working with PowerShell 2.0, or if you need to retain the csv format, you can do the work yourself by refencing the values from `PSCustomObject` into a new hashtable and splat that:

```
Import-Csv .\test.txt |ForEach-Object {
    $Splat = @{}
    $_.psobject.Properties |ForEach-Object { $Splat[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
    .\paramtest.ps1 @Splat
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mathias for your suggestion.  I need to read more into Splatting to understand how the above work so that I can make it easier for user.  Eventually, I would have a regular user put the value into the .txt file and cut and paste the command to get this script running - so I need to KISS(Keep It Simple Simple) this procedure and script.

Comment: Thank you everyone for giving me guidance on this topic.  I had gone with a different approach.  I changed my code to:

Comment: @lmbNbirt If you found an alternative solution on your own, post it as an answer! :-)

Comment: sorry....run out of time for editing....."Thank you everyone for giving me guidance on this topic.  I had gone with a different approach.  I changed my code to:  foreach ($name in get-content "paramtest.txt"){ do-somthing with $name}.  The paramtest.txt is now have only one column of value.  For now, this solution work, but eventually I will have to re-visit the Splatting and use function to get the script working."

Comment: @lmbNbirt As I said: post an answer, not a comment!