# PowerShell: provide parameters in a file

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to provide powershell parameters with a file?
At the moment I have a script which is called `My_Script.ps1`. To start this script I have to provide the right parameters in the command:

```
.\My_Script.ps1 -param1="x" -param2="x" -param3="x" -param4="x" -param5="x" -param6="x" ...
```

This works but it isn't a very easy way to start the script. Is it possible in powershell to use a file in which you store your parameters and to use that file when you start the script?

*Example*

In `My_Script.ps1` I add something like:

```
Param(
   [string]$File="Path/to/file"
   )
```

In my file I have something like

```
param1="x"
param2="x"
param3="x"
param4="x"
...
```

To execute the script you can edit the file and just start the script with `.\My_Script.ps1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [splatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31465488) you can create variables from `=` separated values in a file.

```
param1=foo
param2=bar
param3=herp
param4=derp
```

Don't quote the values. The parameter names should be valid for a variable (no spaces etc.)

- PowerShell 3 and newer:

  ```
  (Get-Content c:\params.ini -raw | ConvertFrom-StringData).GetEnumerator() |
       ForEach { Set-Variable $_.name $_.value }
  ```
- PowerShell 2:

  ```
  ([IO.File]::ReadAllText('c:\params.ini') | ConvertFrom-StringData).GetEnumerator() |
       ForEach { Set-Variable $_.name $_.value }
  ```

The code creates variables in current scope. It's possible to create in a global/script/parent [scope](https://ss64.com/ps/set-variable.html).

Comment: Thanks! I had to replace `Set-Value` with `Set-Variable`. Than it worked. You can edit it if you want.

Comment: Good catch. I've used `sv` in the actual code I tried.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:
Just use a ps1 file as config file and define your variables as you would do in your main script

```
$Param1 = "Value"
$Param2 = 42
```

Then you can use dot-sourcing or import-module to get the data from the config file

```
. .\configfile.ps1
```

or

```
Import-Module .\Configfile.ps1
```

afterwards you can just use the variables

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [blog posting](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/08/20/use-powershell-to-work-with-any-ini-file/)
 for a start and declare your parameters in an ini-like format.

For sure you could also use a csv-like format and work with import-csv cmdlet.